# About mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

Does a payoff matrix like

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
&B&     B&\\
\hline
A& (0,1)& (1,1)\\
A&  (1,1)& (0,1)
\end{array}$$

has infinite number of mixed-strategy Nash Equilibriums?

Assume $B$ chooses column and $A$ chooses row. The probability that $A$ chooses the first row is $p$, so second is $1-p$. So the expected payoff of $B$ is $1-p+p= 1-p+p$ (first column = second column). So I think p can be randomly choosed ranges from $1$ to $0$. But assume the probability that $B$ chooses the first column is $q$ and second column is $1-q$. Then the expected payoff of $A$ is $1-q = q$ (first row = second row). So $q = 0.5$. But it seems that $p$ cannot be randomly choosed...

Comment: Why do you think so? What have you tried?

Comment: Btw: It would make sense to use different names for different actions/strategies.

Comment: Assume B chooses column and A chooses row. The probability that A chooses the first row is p, so second is 1-p. So the expected payoff of B is 1-p+p= 1-p+p (first column = second column). So I think p can be randomly choosed ranges from 1 to 0. But assume the probability that B chooses the first column is q and second column is 1-q. Then the expected payoff of A is 1-q = q (first row = second row). So q = 0.5. But it seems that p cannot be randomly choosed...

Answer (score 0):

Let A choose row, either Up or Down. B chooses column, Left or Right. Given any mixed strategy by A, choosing U with p and D with (1-p), then B's payoff is q(payoff to L)+(1-q)(Payoff to R) or q[p+1-p]+(1-q)[p+1-p]=1.  Hence, given any mixed strategy of A's, any mixed strategy of B's will be a best reply.  Now, what is the payoff to A, and what is the best reply to B? It is to choose p to maximize p(payoff to U)+(1-p)(payoff to D), remembering that B is choosing between L and R with probability q and (1-q).

Comment: So the best reply to B is p(1-2q)+q. And the number of mixed-strategy nash equilibriums is infinite. Am I right?

Comment: Almost. Choose p to maximize p(1-2q)+q.  Depending what q is, that drives p to 0 or 1.  Either way, any q works for B, so there are a continuum of mixed Nash Equilibrium in this case.